# "Many's the time" construction

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, inversion

I presume ***'s*** is abbreviation for ***is*** and not the possessive form. If this is the case, why do we use a singular verb with ***many***?

And why ***time*** and not ***times***?

Comment: Where did you read or hear this phrase?  "Many's the time" does not sound like Standard English to my (American) ear.  I would not recommend learning it, unless you need to speak a dialect that uses this phrase.

Comment: I heard that in American Tune by Paul Simon: "Many’s the time I’ve been mistaken
And many times confused"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The time* is the subject, not *many*:

> Many<sub>predicative complement</sub> 's<sub>copula</sub> the time<sub>subject</sub>

Usually the subject comes before the verb, but in this construction the subject and copular complement are inverted!  How can we tell?

1. *Many* is an adjective, and adjectives can be predicative complements but not subjects.
2. More importantly, the verb changes form to agree with *the time(s)*.  Let's make it plural:

> Many<sub>predicative complement</sub> are<sub>copula</sub> the times<sub>subject</sub>

The verb changes form to *are*!  So we can see that it's agreeing with the right-hand side, not the left-hand side.  (The plural version has the same meaning.)

Following either version is a relative clause of some sort, modifying *the time(s)*.

- It can be a *wh*-relative:

  > Many are the times [ **when** a designer must sacrifice speed to attain some important feature ] .
- It can be a *that*-relative:

  > Many are the times [ **that** he refused payment for his services ] .
- Or it can be a bare relative:

  > Many's the time [ <sub>∅</sub> I've found myself surrounded by a swarm of angry hostiles ] .

Whether it's singular or plural doesn't really change the meaning here.